# Integrate characteristic function ordering n variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Given $n$ variables, consider the characteristic function $\mathbb{1}_{x_1<\ldots<x_n}:[0,1]^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$ where
$$\mathbb{1}_{x_1<\ldots<x_n}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\begin{cases}1&x_1<\ldots<x_n\\0&\text{else}\end{cases}.$$
Furthermore given a constant $c\in[0,1]$ I would like to show that
$$\int_0^c\ldots\int_0^c \mathbb{1}_{x_1<\ldots<x_n}(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\:dt_1\ldots dt_n=\frac{c^{n}}{n!}.$$
I computed it for $n=1,2,3$ which always gave me the correct term.

EDIT:
Okay, I can now prove the result, by:

$\int_0^c\ldots\int_0^c \mathbb{1}_{x_1<\ldots<x_n}(t_1,\ldots,t_n)\:dt_1\ldots dt_n\\
=\int_0^c\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^{x_1}(c-t)^{n-2}\:dt\right)\:dx_1\\
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^c\int_0^{x_1}(c-t)^{n-2}\:dt\:dx_1\\
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^c\int_t^c(c-t)^{n-2}\:dx_1\:dt\\
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^c(c-t)^{n-2}\int_t^c1\:dx_1\:dt\\
=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_0^c(c-t)^{n-1}\:dt\\
=\frac{c^n}{n!}.$

Where the first identity is application of induction and the second to last identity is

$$\int_a^b\left(\int_a^y f(x,y)\:dx\right)\:dy = \int_a^b\left(\int_x^b f(x,y)\:dy\right)\:dx$$.

Which should be an identity following from Fubini's Theorem (at least the internet says so), but I do not see this identity. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral identity is an integral over a right-triangular region in $\mathbb{R}^2$. This means you can perform the integral as an iterated integral in either order. More discussion of why below.

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, a region $E_1$ is of type I if we can find functions $g_i:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2$, so that $$E_1=\{(x,t):a\leq x\leq b, g_1(x)\leq t\leq g_2(x)\}$$ and $E_2$ is of type II if we can find functions $h_i:[k,d]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2$, so that $$E_2=\{(x,t):k\leq t\leq d, h_1(t)\leq x\leq h_2(t)\}.$$

For your example (dropping the subscript on $x_1$): $a=k=0$, $b=d=c$, $h_1(t)=t$, $h_2(t)=c$, $g_1(x)=0$, and $g_2(x)=x$. So your triangular region $E$ is both type I and type II ($E=E_1=E_2$ with the parameters just given). As long as the function $f:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfies certain properties (and specifically, this works if it is continuous like the case here), then
$$\int_{E}f(x,t)d(x,t)=\int_{E_1}f(x,t)d(x,t)=\int_{E_2}f(x,t)d(x,t).$$

The integrals of each type are given as iterated integals:
$$\int_{E_1}f(x,t)d(x,t)=\int_a^b\left(\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)}f(x,t) dt \right) dx $$
$$\int_{E_2}f(x,t)d(x,t)=\int_k^d\left(\int_{h_1(t)}^{h_2(t)}f(x,t) dx \right) dt .$$
The proof of this is a bit longer than I want to type here, but I am looking at it as I type this on page 483, section 12.3 of An Introduction to Analysis by Wade.

When the integral is over a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is `projectable' onto each $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (by removing each variable individually), and you can find suitable upper and lower boundary functions for each projection, then you can integrate the iterated integral in either order.

Comment: Thank you jdods for your answer. It is clear to me, geometrically, why it is possible to change the order of integration there. But I read that this "trick" can be proven by Fubini's Theorem as mentioned above. Can you provide any idea how?

Comment: I don't quite see what the issue is. I must be missing something. This just seems like a standard "switch the order of integration". Doesn't Fubini's Theorem allow that in this case?

Comment: The area of integration of the inner integral depends on the variable of the outer integral. This is not generally a finite sigma-algebra. Hence, the last statement in my question above needs a thorough proof (possibly following from Fubini's Theorem), but Fubini is only applicable in a case like $\int_a^b\left(\int_c^d f(x,y)\:dx\right)\:dy=\int_c^d\left(\int_a^b f(x,y)\:dy\right)\:dx$. Does that clarify the question?

Comment: I've updated the answer. Note that the region is a triangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$. This is a region of both type 1 and type 2, so the iterated integral can be performed in any order. Are you looking for a complete rigorous from-the-ground-up proof? You'll have to find a real analysis text which covers multi-dimensional integrals. Alternatively, maybe you could construct a double Reimann sum. Note that the double Reimann sum is finite, so we can change the order of summation. If both double sums converge. Since they are the same partial sums, the integrals they converge to must be the same.

Comment: Thank you so much, both for the literature reference, which I will have a look at, and your explanation. This does answer my question.